# How to organize exception handling in java on large projects?

Tags: java, exception

I'm familiar with the basic of exception handling including the `try`, `catch`, `throw` and `throws` keywords.

My question is about how one should organize his exception handling on a large project. I could not find a single book or resource that explains how to implement exception in a "standard" way, every resource I found only teaches you the basics.

For example **where should I put the try-catch block?** If we imagine a chain of methods the top link of the chain being the main and the bottom is the method that throws the exception is there a convention for where the try-catch block should be?

- in the main ?
- in the method that call the method that throws the exception ?
- some where in between ?

Thank you.

Comment: I would say it is up to you where you catch exceptions. There are scenarios where you want to catch the exception where it occurs and others where you want the caller to catch them.

Comment: Catch the exceptions where you can actually handle them gracefully.

Comment: I can't add an answer because this is closed, but... Each layer of your app should produce it's own custom exceptions and not bubble up exceptions from a lower layer. e.g. a SQL exception should never leave the persistence layer -- it should be caught and dealt within within the persistence layer. If that exception stops you from processing a request, then a new exception should be raised to that effect (while logging the lower level exception). This applies to all layers -- each layer should have its own exception and not expose lower-level exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can lead to answers which are opinionated depending on the structuring approaches used. But I can just share the standards I follow or my team follows which seems to be very effective and reasonable.

There are some standard assumptions we make before writing any code

1. A method serves a single responsibility. (inline with SR of a class )
2. A method either returns a expected output or raises an exception.
3. We have a set of custom exception classes with a base parent class extended from Exception / Throwable for every unique error scenario

These assumptions / rules has helped us in structuring the code not only in terms of exception but also in having a better maintainable code base. Coming to the exception handling keeping the assumptions in mind,

1. The method bodies are written inside a try/catch block which will potentially catch all possible exceptions (Not RuntimeException / Exception / Throwable)
2. A custom exception can be raised by the method which is relevant to the context with some parameters like a message, error code, or more info defined in the custom exception base.
3. The top most layer of application will catch the base custom exception and can work with the messages and codes accordingly. This layer will also catch a Throwable, to catch all other exceptions and do something like sending a 500 in case of REST API.

In no case, the application will suffer a crash. So IMO, every method with some logical context should use a try/catch block and raise a context oriented exception. The layer just above can catch such an exception and then further customize the exception or throw a different one if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answare chosing the proper way to deal with the exception depending on the categorization of the method seens to be an obvius aprotch after you said it but I had tunner vision on a singlar solution. This really opened my eyes

Comment: *"So IMO, every method with some logical context should use a try/catch block and raise a context oriented exception."* 
I would be conserned with time optimization, catch blocks in particular are time consuming whe actually run. At least by what other post on stackoverflow indicate.

Comment: Happy that it gave you some good insights. Execution of catch blocks should be minimal in a well developed application. If the data quality, logical correctness are already verified, then its a very small thing to be concerned of - again "IMO" :-)